# Duda de restauracion

Tags: python, mysql, centos

tengo una duda, para mysql al restaurar una base que acabo de realizar el respaldo esta tiene como 1 gb menos.
es normal o debo mirar que paso en las tablas?, o en todo caso
existiria una forma de comparar ambas bases tabla por tabla?

Comment: un 1 gb menos en tamaño de archivos? las bases de datos guardan espacio por si acaso.. Tambien los delete pueden provocar que se quiten datos, pero no espacio... el espacio es relativo a lo que la base de datos maneje.. porque pese menos, no quiere decir que hayas perdido datos.. pero en el peor de los casos, hace un count de todas las tablas y comparalos...

Comment: y creo que va a ser lo mejor, solo que son +600 tablas, eso nomas me deja con el martillo entre la cabeza, y si es 1 gb menos literalmente por ejemplo en linea veo 11,9 gb pensa el original, el bkp recien levantado pesa 10,0 GB y no salto ni un error o aviso en el proceso de restauracion del BKP, lo mas raro todavia, en fin, veo como lo voy a tomar, muchas gracias

Comment: si el backup es correcto, entonces no veo porque debas preocuparte...

Comment: Buenas, tiene diferencia, increiblemente, para el conteo de todas las tablas es la siguiente consulta
** SELECT table_name, table_rows
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'BaseDatos'; **

Comment: Ojo que las estadisticas esten actualizadas!!!!

Comment: Buenas, efectivamente es la version, baje al 5.7 y apenas 27 registros son las diferencias